# iperf3 - results interpretation

Tags: iperf3

Recently I've done some network testing with iperf3 (3.1.7 on Linux) and I'm confused about the results.

The syntax I'm using is `iperf3 -c -b 500M`, both for TCP and UDP testing. My understanding is that by default, iperf3 does some kind of internal pacing to maintain desired rate.

I have read that in newer versions of iperf3 timers that control the pacing mechanism have pretty good resolution (1 ms), so the traffic shouldn't be very bursty.

Thing is that for UDP testing I'm getting packet loss (1%-2%), while TCP testing reaches maximum desired bandwidth and reports no retransmissions.

I don't have a good insight about how the pacing exactly works, but I tend to think that if it's similar both for TCP/UDP **and** the issue was on the network, I should expect consistent results for UDP/TCP (so, retransmissions in case of TCP).

Has anyone experienced similar results? If so, what was the reason of this inconsistency?

Comment: Data sent via TCP is tracked by the stack and automatically retransmitted if lost - without iperf3 seeing that. Testing with UDP shows the actual packet loss ratio.

Comment: This is true, but still iperf3 reports retransmissions, if they occur. In case of network issue, available bandwidth reported by iperf3 should be lower than set with -b option, too.

Comment: You have not given us any idea about the network. What your hosts/servers do is off-topic here. We could try to help with the network, but we need things like a good network description or diagram, the network device models, the network device configurations, logs or debugs, interface statistics, etc.

Comment: Hi Ron. You seem to assume that the issue is in the network. I'm not sure about that. This is a general question about behavior of this measurement tool. If my reasoning is correct, the problem is in the tool - there are plenty of threads about iperf not giving accurate/consistent results, although I haven't found my exact scenario. I think that network guys have the most experience with this tool, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: We can only help with the network. What goes on in the hosts and application is off-topic here, and the hosts can have a large effect on your results.